# Why using VcXsrv for WSL when you can use xrdp?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, windows, xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying the VcXsrv X11 Server to use with my WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 but I have found much better to use xrdp.

Since it is a local connection network speed doesn't matter and it feels almost like native X Server.

But the most important is that I have encountered 0 problems as I can run software which would previously cause VcXsrv to hang (like Rstudio or Gimp etc...)

On top of that since xrdp can forward audio so you can get audio in you WSL which you cannot do if you use VcXsrv (unless you try to run PulseServer on Windows 10 but good luck with that since Pulse Windows code is already 8 years old!)

And plenty of other goodies like sharing printers and disks and ports with Windows etc...)

Last but not least, you can even remote desktop connect to your Ubuntu / WSL

If someone is interested I can post the setup procedure here...

Just let me know.

Comment: You can do a full Q/A of your own findings here.  It may help others.  Change it into a question, then select the answer your own question below.

Comment: This is not a real question? Even if you were looking for help, the answers would necessarily be opinion based, as your post is.

Comment: I think it would be very useful... It just has to be turned into a Q & R form. Maybe a question like _How do I set up WSL to use XRDP?_ would be okay (could be judged as too broad by some), or even a series of more focused questions such as _How to do X in WSL with XRDP?_, where X is audio, remote desktop and the other goodies you mention. Just avoid going into comparisons (VcXsrv vs XRDP) unless necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that using VcXsrv, you can get higher frame rates, but yes I agree that XRDP is much better. Could you share your method of getting sound to work? Can't seem to find that anywhere.

There's also a neat application where you can launch individual apps you have installed in WSL with a GUI interface that works with VcXsrv because it can open apps without an entire desktop experience:
https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher

Comment: The question is why using VcXsrv instead of xRDP. I responded by saying some of the benefits of VcXsrv, then responded to the comment mentioned about posting the setup by asking about how they got audio to work, so there's no need to downvote. Also, since I was a new member, I was unable to comment at the time

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hassle to put all the various bits together so I [wrote a script](https://github.com/DesktopECHO/xWSL) that does it for you.  It downloads Ubuntu from the Windows Store and installs xRDP with a basic XFCE4 desktop environment.